# How to make table pagination with bootstrap-table plugin

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

In my project, I use bootstap-table plugin for table pagination.

The url of bootstrap-table is :

```
http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/getting-started/
```

I have downloded the code and used in my page.

But unlucky, it worked fail. Here is my code:

```
<script>
$("#xzy").bootstrapTable({ 
  striped: true,  
  pagination: true,
  pageList: [10, 20],
  pageSize: 10, 
  pageNumber: 1, 
  sidePagination:'client',
  sortName: 'id',
  sortOrder: 'desc', 
  columns: [{
    field: 'id',
    title: 'Item ID'
     }, {
    field: 'name',
    title: 'Item Name'
    }, {
    field: 'price',
    title: 'Item Price'
    }],
  data: [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Item 1',
    price: '$1'
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Item 2',
    price: '$2'
}]
});
</script>
</head>  

<body style="height:100%" >  
<table data-toggle="table" id="xzy"></table>
</body>
```

Here is including file:

```
<link href="jsui/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="jsui/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="bootstrap-table-1.12.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript" src="jsui/easyui-1.5.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsui/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-table-1.12.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-table-1.12.1/dist/bootstrap-table-zh-CN.js"></script>
```

But it works fail.

Today, I tried another way that is for sever way.
Here is my code:

```
var allS="Init";
$("#xzy").bootstrapTable({ 
  url: "idcCCA_at.php", 
  dataType: "json",
  striped: true, 
  pagination: true, 
  pageList: [10, 20], 
  pageSize: 10,
  pageNumber: 1,
  sidePagination: 'server', 
  queryParams:{allS:allS},
  columns: [
      {
          checkbox: true, 
          align: 'center' 
      }, {
          field: 'one', 
          title: 'one'
      }, {
          field: 'two',
          title: 'two'
      }, {
          field: 'three',
          title: 'three'
      }, {
          field: 'four',
          title: 'four'
      }, {
          field: 'five',
          title: 'five'
      },{
          field: 'six',
          title: 'six'
      }
  ]
});
```

And idcCCA_at.php code is :

```
if(isset($_POST['allS']))
{
include("DB.php"); //login DB code

 $sql="select one,two,three,four,five,six from sheet_A where one='John';";
 $stmt=$conn->query($sql);
 $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 $tmpArr = array(
    'one'=>$row['one'],
    'two'=>$row['two'],
    'three'=>$row['three'],
    'four'=>$row['foue'],
    'five'=>$row['five'],
    'six'=>$row['six'],
    );
 echo json_encode($tmpArr);
 }
```

Unlucky, It works fail again.It seems nothing wrong, who can help me?

Comment: are you trying to do server side or client side pagination?

Comment: @JeffB. I am try client side pagination. I define init data at bootstrapTable when page is loaded

Comment: @JeffB.see my update, thank you!

Comment: when I get to work tomorrow I will post my code. is your table loading and functioning without any pagination configured? that is step 1, get table functional then enable pagination.

Comment: I have deleted queryParams function. All i need is the DB data , and then display on my web page table.

Comment: I would start with as few options as possible, get the table working with no pagination, and then add an option at a time. for example, you can sort your data server side. try url and datatype only.

Comment: queryParams is simply for passing additional variables to your server code. it isn't required. it will pass pagination variables etc. automatically.

Answer (score 0):

my html code (this is a copy and paste of my working copy with server pagination).

```
$('#master').bootstrapTable({
    url: './lookup/gettubing.php?d='+$.now(),
    pagination: true,
    sidePagination: 'server',
    pageSize: '25',
    pageList: '[25, 50, 100, All]',
    showRefresh: true,
    columns:[
        ...
    ]
});
```

and my php server file

```
include("../../Includes/aedclass.php"); 
$nconn = new WorkData();
$conn = new PDO ($nconn->DB_DSN,$nconn->DB_USER,$nconn->DB_PASSWORD);

$offset = $_GET['offset'];
$limit = $_GET['limit'];

//calculate start & end
    if ($offset>0){
        $start = $offset+1;}
    else{
        $start = $offset;}      
    $end = $offset + $limit;


$data = array();

//get total record count and pass to json
$sql = "SELECT count(*)
    FROM master_well_list, tubing_size 
    WHERE master_well_list.api = tubing_size.api";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

$rowcnt = $result[0];

$data = array();
$data['total']=$rowcnt;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY field, pad, well_name, well_num)
        AS RowNumber, well_name, well_num, field, pad
    FROM master_well_list, tubing_size
    WHERE master_well_list.api = tubing_size.api)   AS TEST
    WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN $start AND $end";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$data['sql']=$sql;
$data['rows']=$result;

echo json_encode($data);
```

for client side html code

```
$('#master').bootstrapTable({
    url: './lookup/gettubing.php?d='+$.now(),
    pagination: true,
    sidePagination: 'client',
    pageSize: '25',
    pageList: '[25, 50, 100, All]',
    showRefresh: true,
    columns:[
        ...
    ]
});
```

server side

```
include("../../Includes/aedclass.php"); 
$nconn = new WorkData();
$conn = new PDO ($nconn->DB_DSN,$nconn->DB_USER,$nconn->DB_PASSWORD);


$sql = "SELECT well_name, well_num, field, pad
    FROM master_well_list, tubing_size
    WHERE master_well_list.api = tubing_size.api";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Thankyou for your kindly hearted. Refer to your practice, I have found the problem.

Comment: @stack great to hear, glad you got it working! this is a wonderful community.

Answer (score 0):

Change these code:

```
  $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $tmpArr = array(
   'one'=>$row['one'],
   'two'=>$row['two'],
   'three'=>$row['three'],
   'four'=>$row['foue'],
   'five'=>$row['five'],
    'six'=>$row['six'],
   );
echo json_encode($tmpArr);
```

to these code:

```
$row=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($row);
```